# Am I freeing memory properly?

Tags: c, memory-management

Okay, so I have a homework assignment for a C programming class and I just finished with the output doing what I expected. However, I am still a bit confused on memory allocation and freeing.

Basically what has me question my self is the freeing of the structure memory and the "Change_name" function.  In my program I am just taking the new name and setting the value who.name to the new name.  But what happens to the "old" name in this scenario? when I call free(who), is the old name being deleted?

any clarification would be appreciated!

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

/* complete this function, which initialize the fileds of the struct, and return a pointer to the initialzied struct */
struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);
    (*who).name = name;
    (*who).age = age;
    (*who).height = height;
    (*who).weight = weight;

    return who;
}

/* complete this function, which free memory that was allocated for a struct*/ 

void Person_destroy(struct Person *who)
{
    assert(who != NULL);
    free(who);

}
/* complete this function, which print the value of member of struct for the input argument */ 

void Person_print(struct Person *who)
{
    printf("This person have the values of...\n");
    printf("name: %s\n", (*who).name);
    printf("age: %d\n", (*who).age);
    printf("height: %d\n", (*who).height);
    printf("weight: %d\n", (*who).weight);


}
/* complete this function, which change the value of filed member of the struct to the value of newName */
void Change_name (struct Person *who, char * newName)
{
    (*who).name = newName;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // make two people structures
    struct Person *joe = Person_create(
            "Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);

    struct Person *frank = Person_create(
            "Frank Blank", 20, 72, 180);

    // print them out and where they are in memory
    printf("Joe is at memory location %p:\n", joe);
    Person_print(joe);

    printf("Frank is at memory location %p:\n", frank);
    Person_print(frank);

    // make changes in filed of goe's struct print them again
    joe->age += 20;
    joe->height -= 2;
    joe->weight += 40;
    Change_name(joe, "Jack The third Junior Smith Benedickt"); 
    Person_print(joe);


    // destroy them both so we clean up
    Person_destroy(joe);
    Person_destroy(frank);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `->` instead of `(*who).`? `(*who).name = name;` would be `who->name = name;`, and so on...

Comment: BTW you do not need to check for `who == NULL` before passing to `free`, which tolerates a `NULL pointer`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Nothing wrong with checking for unexpected conditions, really.

Comment: @JeffreyQuinn The old name isn’t being deleted, but that’s fine because it wasn’t allocated dynamically. It’s read-only and part of the program’s data (a string literal). Plus, as a general structure thing, since `Person_create` doesn’t `strdup()` the name or otherwise copy it, `Person_destroy` isn’t responsible for freeing it.

Comment: @Ryan thank you for the clarification! I am going to have to look more into variables becoming read-only...this is something we haven't discussed in lecture yet.

Comment: @pzaenger I use (*who). because most of what I deal with is C#/Java/Javascript and the dot notation feels a little closer to home

Comment: The `char *name;` struct member is easy here, because the string literal pointers you provide are persistent, and do not need to (cannot) be `free`d. More care will be needed when the names come from data entry into an array, possibly allocated memory. When you get to that, you'll need to `free` the `name` memory before you `free` the struct memory.

Comment: C is not C#, Java or Javascript. When in Rome do as Romans do.

Comment: The rule is simple: For each value returned by `malloc(...)/calloc(...)/realloc(NULL, ...) /strdup(...)` there needs to be exactly *one* call to `free()` passing this very value.

Comment: `(*who).name = name;` is going to bite you in the arse: `Person_create` should take a `const char *`, and you should allocate memory to hold a copy (`strdup`). Once you do that, you'll need to `free(who->name)` before freeing `who` itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR: For your specific example: yes, but there are caveats to what you're doing.

One question that needs addressing WRT `change_name` is this:

***ut what happens to the "old" name in this scenario? when I call free(who), is the old name being deleted?***

For reasons that, I hope, will become clear further down, there is no clear answer to this question. Your code assigns a `char *` blindly. You don't *know* where that string is stored. If it's a string constant with static storage (either global variable or `const char *` in main), that old name will remain in memory for as long as your application runs. If it's dynamically allocated, unsetting a pointer doesn't free the memory either. assigning a new pointer can potentially cause you to leak memory. The safest way is to copy the string (`strdup`), and `free` the pointer prior to changing the `name` field.

---

There's an underlying problem here: You can only free memory in the right way if you allocate it correctly. Strictly speaking, you are doing just that. However, a function that takes a `char *` shouldn't blindly assign that same pointer. The pointer might be a stack `char[]` that decayed into a pointer (because it was passed as an argument).

You have no idea where that string was allocated, how, and most importantly: how long the pointer will remain valid. A couple of scenario's where a `char *` can cause problems:

```
int main ( void )
{
    struct Person *p = foobar();
    printf("name => %s?", p->name);
    Person_destroy(p);
    return 0;
}

struct Person *foobar( void )
{
    char bar[] = "this is a local string";
    return Person_create(bar, 32, 64, 140);
}
```

The pointer to `bar` expires once `foobar` returns, so this is a problem (stack memory pointers).

A pointer on the heap might suffer from the same problem:

```
struct Person *foobar( void )
{
    const char *x = "Name";
    char *bar = strdup(x); // allocates on heap and copies string
    // check for null's etc...
    struct Person *person =  Person_create(bar, 32, 64, 140);
    //some more stuff happens, including:
    bar = realloc(bar, strlen(x) + 255);
    strncat(bar, " has been successfully allocated", 33);
    return person;
}
```

The problem here is that `realloc` might `memmove` the original string, and return an entirely new pointer, in which case the `name` field of the struct will become invalid. If that doesn't happen, `person->name` now points to `Name has been successfully allocated`, which is a potential bug.

So I strongly advise you to copy the name string:

```
                        // note: const char *name
struct Person *Person_create(const char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof *who); // shorter to write, more reliable
    if (who == NULL)
         exit(1);// or whatever
    who->name = strdup(name); // create copy
    //etc...

    return who;
}
```

This means, of course that `struct Person` will need to free the `name` pointer:

```
void Person_destroy(struct Person *who)
{
    free(who->name);
    free(who);
}
```

Double indirection is a bit risky a lot of the time, but imagine someone doing something like this:

```
int main( void )
{
    struct Person *p = Person_create("Name", 1, 2, 3);
    //do stuff
    Person_destroy(p);
    // more stuff, eg:
    printf("%p\n", (void *)p);
    Person_destroy(p);
    return 0;
}
```

This is not good,. `p` should be null'ed after freeing it. Freeing an invalid pointer is bad, mkay. 2 ways to make this a less common problem:

```
#define FREE_PERSON(p) do {\
    Person_destroy(p);\
    p = NULL;\
} while(0);
```

This macro will always set the person variable to `NULL` after calling `Person_destroy`. The downside is: it's a clunky macro, and people can (and will) bypass it.

Change `Person_destroy` a bit:

```
void Person_destroy(struct Person **p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return; // this is needed now
    struct Person *tmp = *p;
    free(tmp->name);
    free(tmp);
    *p = NULL; // set the pointer itself to NULL
}
```

This forces people to call `Person_destroy` with a pointer to their pointer, and automatically sets their pointer to `NULL`.
Again, good practice requires devs to do this themselves, but it's a trivial change and helps prevent problems over time.

#### [Demo](https://eval.in/742209) using the double-indirection approach

Comment: Thank you for the clairfication, I marked your answer as correct as it went into a good depth and would most likely be more benfifical to people who stumble across this post in the future.

Comment: Is the `struct Person *tmp = *p;` a stylistic choice or necessary in C?

Comment: Setting `tmp` to `NULL` won't change the value of `*p` so doesn't have the desired effect.

Comment: @ChrisTurner should've said `*p = NULL` updated answer and added demo

Comment: @OliverJanKrylow: `tmp` is a stylistic choice, I don't like working with multiple levels of indirection, and a tmp variable is an easy way to avoid having to write things like `(*p)->name`. Multiple levels of indirection make code harder to read/maintain, especially when structs contain pointers to other structs etc...

Comment: Note that `strdup()` isn't a standard function, so it might not be available on your platform, or might have different behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `Person_destroy` doesn't free any of the names because you're just freeing `who`. But that's OK because you're also not dynamically allocating any of the names with `malloc`/`strdup`/etc...